# Add Tab Bar to all screens even if that screen isn't immediately accessible by tab button

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a tab bar in my app that has 3 items leading to 3 separate view controllers. However, within one of those pages I have a button transition to another view controller (click on the button and it takes you to another page), and the tab on the bottom is no longer visible.

Think of Instagram where you can search for a person...if you click on that person's profile, the tab on the bottom is still visible and responsive, while the tab bar in my app is not. I need that same effect that Instagram has in my app, however I am confused on how to achieve that.

Comment: Make use of ContentView in Your TabVC let's say **controller1** and navigate Views inside that **controller1** using a **NavigationController Don't present there**

Comment: @iOSGeek can u pls try to explain a little more clearly and write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample Project to explain what I was trying to explain

**Screenshot - Storyboard**

[image]

**View Hierarchy**

```
---> Tab Controller
  ---> Tab Vc 1 --> ContentView With Navigation Controller
  ---> Tab Vc 2 --> ContentView With Navigation Controller
  ---> Tab Vc 3 --> ContentView With Navigation Controller
---> Demo Vc - Which wis the second ViewController to be displayed with in Tab Bar bounds
```

**Output**

[image]

**Project Link**

Link - `https://github.com/RockinGarg/ContainerView-TabBar.git`

check branch - `stack_Tab_VC_Container`

clone - `git clone -b stack_Tab_VC_Container https://github.com/RockinGarg/ContainerView-TabBar.git`

Comment: This looks better, thanks. I'll try to implement it in my project and if it looks like it fixes the issue I'll upvote you and give you answer check.

Comment: Just try implementing, if any issue occurs fell free to ask

Comment: Also, by ContentView do you mean container view?

Comment: Hi, it's working very well. Only one issue I have found that when changing tabs navigation controller doesn't show the root view controller rather it shows the inside navigated view, how we can navigate to the root view controller when tabs are changed?